# Some basic questions about Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, oop

I have some basic Questions about Objective-C:

I. When I want to access a instance method of an object, do I always have to allocate it first, to access the method? Even if I have already allocated it somewhere else?

E.G:

```
CustomPerson *person = [[CustomPerson alloc] init];
[person getName];

// can't I do something like this? (
[get_instance_of_already_somewhere_allocated_person getName];
```

II. As a beginner, should I start with ARC enabled?

III. What is the difference between instance variables and @property-variables? I mean when I access them in my methods, aren't they both "global" in my instance?

E.G:

```
// CustomPerson.h
@interface CustomPerson : NSObject {
    UIImageView *_person;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *img;


// CustomPerson.m
@implementation CustomPerson

@synthesize img = _img;

- (id)init
{
    img.image = @"someimage.png";
    _person.image = @"someimage.png";
    [self setImageToSomeOtherImage:@"rustyimage.png"];
}

- (void)setImageToSomeOtherImage:(NSString *)img
{
    // img.image before was "someimage.png"
    img.image = img;
    // _person.image before was "someimage.png"
    _person.image = img;
}

@end
```

Comment: There's a lot of questions here.  You should probably do a bit of research on some of them.

Comment: For start you should never return void in init method. You can read more on it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init)

Comment: You init method is wrong. You don't allocate and initialize instance variables, you do not call the super init, and you do not return the object allocated by returning self. Look into code on how to create initializers: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MultipleInitializers.html

Comment: ok ok lol. I've just made a typo there. also: this was just an arbitrary example.

Comment: A question on Stack Overflow should contain only one question, not three. It would've been more correct to post each of these as a separate question. (In so doing, the built-in duplicate check would probably have told you about the already-existing question for #2.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

I. to use an object you have to allocate and initialize it first. Once this is done you can use the object many times, calling methods on it, etc.

II. I recommend using ARC. It will be simpler for you. Once you have more knowledge you can go back and understand memory management.

III. A property is an instance variable that comes with a setter and a getter. Apple recommends that you only access instance variables directly in the init or dealloc methods. In other methods you should use getter and setter to get/change the instance variable.